# Table open another table when I choose one of cell HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I need help because I need to create a table to open another table when I choose a cell. I need to do this in HTML or JavaScript.

I have a table with some cells that have data and when I choose one of then I need other table with other data to open below.

Can someone give me a idea of how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do is have the other table already below it, and with CSS, change the `display` to `none` and then have it execute in with JavaScript later. Here is my code done in JQuery:

```js
$("#tableOne").click(function() {
  $("#tableTwo").css("display", "block");
});
```

```css
#tableTwo {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id = "tableOne">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button id = "demo">Click Me!</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id = "tableTwo">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Yay!</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my regular JavaScript:

```js
            var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
            demo.onclick = function() {
               document.getElementById("tableTwo").style.display = "block";
            }
```

```css
#tableTwo {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
    <table id = "tableOne">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button id = "demo">Click Me!</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table id = "tableTwo">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Yay!</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function displaySecondTable(){
            document.getElementById("tableTwo").innerHTML=" (here is the code for your second table) ";
        }    
    </script>
</head>

    <body>

    <table id = "tableOne">
      <tr>
        <td onclick="displaySecondTable()">
          Click here
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>    

    <table id = "tableTwo" />

</body>
</html>
```

You can do it in pure javascript ;)

Comment: Thank so much, bro.
This codes save me and gave me a light from my activity in my office. 
Thank so much!